# Range Union not adding additional range to existing range - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add an entire row to a range in two different moments, in the first `for each` the row is added perfectly however in the second `for each` the values are not being added to the range. I do not understand why, can anyone help me?

PS: I performed a debug and the condition `linha.value ="CRDI"` is fulfilled and the `"Set DadosCopiados = Union(DadosCopiados, linha.EntireRow)"` is executed. However the values are not added.

This is not the complete code.

```
Dim DadosCopiados As Range

For Each linha In FolhaOrigem.Range(Col_Letter & "2:" & Col_Letter & UltimaLinhaOrigem)
    count = count + 1
    If (linha.Value Like "17*") Then

        If (FolhaOrigem.Range(Col_Letter2 & count).Value <> "E") Then

            If DadosCopiados Is Nothing Then
                Set DadosCopiados = linha.EntireRow
            Else
                Set DadosCopiados = Union(DadosCopiados, linha.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next linha

For Each linha In FolhaOrigem.Range(Col_Letter3 & "2:" & Col_Letter3 & UltimaLinhaOrigem)

    If (linha.Value = "CRDI" Or linha.Value = "GARP") Then

            If DadosCopiados Is Nothing Then
                Set DadosCopiados = linha.EntireRow
            Else
                'line below is not adding new range to existing one
                Set DadosCopiados = Union(DadosCopiados, linha.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
Next linha
```

Comment: Are you certain there is at least one point where `(linha.Value = "CRDI" Or linha.Value = "GARP")` evaluates to `TRUE`?

Comment: Yes there is, I performed a debug and the condition is fulfilled and the "Set DadosCopiados = Union(DadosCopiados, linha.EntireRow)" is executed. However the values are not added.

Comment: How do you confirm the values (range/cells) are not added to the range `DadosCopiados`? What additional debug steps do you take *after* you confirm the statement executes without raising an error?

Comment: Because I inspected (watched) the Dadoscopiados variable and the values are not there when the union is performed.

Comment: Is it possible, that the rows you are trying to add in the **Second loop** are already in the `DadosCopiados` range from **First loop**?

Comment: No, they are different. I do not understand why is not working

Comment: Like Branislav said, if you try to union a cell that already exists in the range, usually there is some kind of error that will occur. You might want to try adding If Intersect(DadosCopiados, linha.EntireRow) Is Nothing before doing the assignment.

Comment: The values are all different, therefore it should be working right? If I remove the first loop the second loop works perfectly and the information is added

Comment: You are adding entire rows to the range. The question is, **are the values on different rows than the loop before**. I already asked this, sorry for repeating myself, but *you confirmed that the second loop by itself is working correctly*, I see no other explanation. You are adding the same rows to the range, therefore the range "doesn't change". **There are no typos in your code, the code is written correctly**. Your range should something like this at the end : `$1:$1,$4:$4,$7:$8`